# How to disable auto-comment feature in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

How can I stop Netbeans from automatically inserting asterisks and `*/` when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Here is a gif I created to illustrate what I'm talking about:
[image]

You can see that when I insert a newline character, Netbeans automatically adds spaces and `**/`. How do I disable that feature? I looked everywhere in the settings and can't find it.

**Edit:** Note that I'm not referring to the automatically generated comment block that generates when you enter `/**` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> above a function definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This well-known [issue](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=230814) has been solved in NetBeans 10.0:

jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-947

[image]

Comment: Finally! But why on earth is it hidden in "Code completion"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a [known issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814).

You can use

```
SHIFT + ENTER
```

to avoid this autocompletion, temporarily.